# PHP replace newlines stored in MySQL DB

Tags: php, regex, newline

I have a MySQL table with 2 columns:

1. `text`: stores a multi-line text which could have line breaks as `\n, \r, \r\n...`. The text is inserted via a webform and could have been inserted by any browser on any OS.
2. `line_break`: represents what type of line break this particular text will use (could be `\n`, `<br>`, `<br />`, ...). This is also inserted via a webform by a user.

In PHP I then do the replacement:

```
$text = preg_replace ("/(\r\n|\r|\n)/", $row['line_break'], $row['text']);
```

Interestingly, if the line break is stored in the DB as `\n` I will actually show `\n` instead of the newline. On the other hand, the following regexp will work correctly:

```
$text = preg_replace ("/(\r\n|\r|\n)/", "\n", $row['text']);
```

How do I need to store the newline in the DB for it to "work" correctly?

Comment: what does mysql do with this question?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: the word MySQL is present in the title, in the text and actually this question is about MySQL as the user wants to now `How do I need to store the newline in the DB for it to "work" correctly?`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In php, `"\n"` is a special notation for writing that special character that means 'line break'.  But if you store the actual text `\n` in your database, you have just that text, and not the line break character. You have what you get when you write `'\n'` or `"\\n"` in PHP. Make sure you store the actual line break character in your database and not the literal `\n` text.

Comment: @GolezTirol, how do I make the user insert the actual linebreak  character? To add the second slash I have tried with addslashes, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Just let them type an enter in a text-area, or use `str_replace` to replace `'\n'` with `"\n"`.